# How to get maxOccurs value from xsd into Java

Tags: java, xml, soap, wsdl

I am running a local webservice application with my wsdl and java. I have provided a tag "maxOccurs='2'" to the element in xsd file. When I run wsdl file, I want to fetch the value of tag 'maxOccurs' in java file and use this value to evalute my java operations.

Can somebody please explain how can I fetch the value of 'maxOccurs' from xsd into Java code?

Comment: MaxOccur attribute will not be visible on your java pojo. 
The attribute will be visible as list , and then you can check the size of the list.

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21929157/how-to-get-the-minoccurs-maxoccurs-values-from-the-xsd-in-java-using-jaxb